# Generating signal in a different frequency band than another signal but transmitted at the same time

Tags: digital-communications, power-spectral-density

I have a signal $x(t)$ of bandwidth $W_1$ transmitted over carrier frequency $f_1$, and another signal $i(t)$ of bandwidth $W_2$ transmitted over carrier frequency $f_2$. The main lobe of both signals' spectrums don't overlap. They are transmitted on the same time. So the passband received signal can be expressed as

$$r(t)=x(t)+i(t)+z(t)$$

and the corresponding baseband signal is (relative to the carrier frequency $f_1$)

$$\tilde{r}(t)=\tilde{x}(t)+\tilde{i}(t)e^{j2\pi(f_2-f_1)t}+\tilde{z}(t)$$

where $\sim$ over a signal means the corresponding baseband signal, and $z(t)$ is additive white Gaussian noise process of zero mean and power spectral density $N_0$.

Although $\tilde{i}(t)e^{j2\pi(f_2-f_1)t}$ doesn't actually interfere with $\tilde{x}(t)$, its spectrum is assumed to appear in the power spectrum density of $\tilde{r}(t)$ at the output of the analog-to-digital converter by sampling the received signal $\tilde{r}(t)$ at a sampling rate $f_s$, where the frequency range of the double-sided PSD is $[-\frac{f_s}{2},\frac{fs}{2}]$.

I want to model the above system in MATLAB, however I have doubts on how to generate $\tilde{i}(t)$. If $\tilde{i}(t)$ interfered with $\tilde{x}(t)$, I would define the signal-to-noise ratio (SNR) and signal-to-interference ratio (SIR) and the received signal can be written as

$$y(t)=\sqrt{\mathtt{SNR}}\left[x(t)+\sqrt{\mathtt{SIR}^{-1}}i(t)\right]+n(t)$$

where $n(t)$ is additive white Gaussian noise process of zero mean and power unity.

In my case, can I write the received signal as

$$y(t)=\left[\sqrt{\mathtt{SNR}_x}x(t)+n_x(t)\right]+\left[\sqrt{\mathtt{SNR}_i}i(t)+n_i(t)\right]$$

where $\mathtt{SNR}_x$ and $\mathtt{SNR}_i$ are the SNR of the signals $x(t)$ and $i(t)$, respectively, and $n_x(t)$ and $n_i(t)$ are additive white Gaussian processes of zero mean and normalized power?

EDIT

Can I write the passband received signal as

$$r(t)=\Re\left\{\left[x(t)+n_x(t)\right]e^{j2\pi f_1t}+\left[i(t)+n_i(t)\right]e^{j2\pi f_2t}\right\}$$

such that when I find the baseband signal with respect to $f_1$ I get

$$y(t)=x(t)+n_x(t)+e^{j2\pi (f_2-f_1)t}\left[i(t)+n_i(t)\right]$$

assuming $n_x(t)$ has a normalized [unit] power over bandwidth $W_1$, while $n_i(t)$ has a normalized power over bandwidth $W_2$?

In practice, both signal will experience the same additive noise sample at the front-end receiver, that's where my confusion is!

Comment: Note that the "So (the received signal can…)" in your first paragraph is not an implication in the logical sense: you can add up any two signals, no matter whether they spectrally overlap or not.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're sampling, at which rate. I understand your sampling rate is $f_s$, but that would mean that the representable frequency range is $[-f_s/2;+f_s/2]$, and not centered around $f_1$. Did you forget to mention a mixer? What's the bandwidth of your anti-aliasing filter?

Comment: @MarcusMüller OK, let's consider the baseband signals by shifting the frequency of the signals by $f_1$ so that the the main lobe of the $x(t)$ is centered around 0, while that of $i(t)$ around $f_2-f_1$ assuming $f_2>f_1$. What do you mean exactly when you say "It's really not clear what you're sampling, at which rate"? At the front-end receiver I have a received signal $r(t)$ and I sample this signal at rate $f_s$. I assume that the intended receiver of $x(t)$ is not the same at the intended receiver of $i(t)$.

Comment: can you please do this clarification in the question text? what is not clear is exactly what I wrote, at which point you're sampling what. You're just claiming you're sampling *something*.

Comment: @MarcusMüller You are right, when I read it again it wasn't clear. I edited the question

Comment: but your edit says you're directly sampling $r$, so that you're **not** in baseband, as your comment claims. And the frequency range representable by the sampled signal then is *not* $[f_1-f_s/2;f_1+f_s/2]$ but $[-f_s/2;+f_s/2]$.

Comment: See my last edits.

Comment: ah cool! Yeah, that's pretty precise in its presentation, +1!

Comment: The notation is still kind hard to follow. Your first equation and your last two equation have different definitions for the same thing $r(t)$ If you take this literal you can only conclude $\sqrt{SNR}=1$ etc. That's probably not what you mean, Another thing you need to define is whether $f_s$ is "large enough" to fully capture signal or if you want/need to deal with aliasing as well.

Comment: @Hilmar In the first equation the noise power is not normalized. In the last two, the noise is normalized, and captured in SNR. Yes, I assume $f_s$ large enough, with no anti-aliasing effects

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't change the fact that your notation is ambiguous which makes it hard to give a precise answer. $r(t)$ is either the thing defined in the first equation or the thing in the last two. It can't be both. I'm not trying to nit-picky here, I'm genuinely confused.  In fact I assume if your were to be more rigorous about your notation the answer may emerge much easier.

Comment: @Hilmar I tried to change the notation. I hope it's less confusing now.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't fully understand the question but I'll take a swing at it: Let's start with the initial definition

$$r(t) = x(t) + i(t) + z(t) \tag{1}$$

If we want to write this in a power normalized form we get

$$r(t) = a\frac{x(t)}{x_{RMS}} +  b\frac{i(t)}{i_{RMS}}  +  c\frac{z(t)}{z_{RMS}} $$

where $x_{RMS} = \sqrt{<x^2(t)>}$ and $<>$ the mean value operator.

$a,b,c$ are gain values that you can adjust as needed and expressed in terms of SNR, SIR, etc as you see fit. This will depend on how exactly you define these quantities. The power of white noise is a function of bandwidth which is in turn a function of the sample rate. Personally I would define SNR only over the bandwidth of the signal, since any reasonable receiver would use a band pass to filter out the rest. But that depends on the goals of your model.

Comment: I want to get the PSD of the received signal immediately after analog-to-digital converter. My question is how can I generate the signals in MATLAB when they are not interfering, i.e., the main lobe of $i(t)$ doen't overlap with the main lobe of the $x(t)$.

Comment: why don't you just create the (bandlimited) base band signals and modulate them up ?

Comment: My issue is with the scaling. What should I scale each signal with to be accurate in the presence of a normalized noise?

Comment: I thought I answered that: just normalize all signals to unity power and then scale to your desired target SNR (in whatever way you define this). It's not clear to me how exactly you define "normalized noise" in this context since you are looking at a much larger bandwidth then you would need for the signal of interest. So this depends on what exactly you want to do with the results

Comment: I would like to detect if there is a signal in the PSD spectrum of the received signal outside the main lobe of $x(t)$. You're exactly right, the problem is with noise. If they signals interfered, I can write the received signal  in baseband (relative to the carrier frequency $f_1$ as $$r(t)=\sqrt{\mathrm{SNR}}\left[x(t)+\sqrt{\mathrm{SIR}}i(t)\right]+z(t)$$ where all the signals $x(t)$, $i(t)$ and $z(t)$ are normalized to unit power. What is not clear to me, is how to write this equation if $i(t)$ doesn't interfere with $x(t)$. Do I need to split the noise signal, or I can keep it as it is?

Comment: See my last edit if it changes something

Comment: In my opinion the use of the term SIR doesn't make sense in this context. If you still want to use it, you need to define precisely what you mean by that. Then just follow this definition. This definition will depend on what it is exactly what you are trying to do. Even the use of SNR is questionable here: You need to specify whether it's over the frequency range of the signal or the full range of the received signal $[0,f_s/2]$. You can use either one, but you need to specify it based on your application.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I totally agree, SIR makes no sense if $i(t)$ doesn't interfere with $x(t)$. This allowed me to think more about the problem, and I want to assume the noise bandwidth to be $W_1$ for all signals. This makes sense when $i(t)$ interferes with $x(t)$ because the received signal will pass through a low pass filter of bandwidth $W_1$, since $x(t)$ is the desired signal, while in the case of no interference, I also will use noise bandwidth $W_1$, although it could be $W_2$

Comment: The noise bandwidth needs to be whatever is correct for your application. If you want to run the received signal through a bandpass anyway, the whole question doesn't make a lot of sense

Comment: True, but before the bandpass/baseband filtering, I want to detect if there is a signal in the whole frequency bandwidth of the received signal that's determined by the sampling frequency $f_s$.